# How to download from Nexus a folder of artifacts (mass download)?

Tags: nexus

I want to move a set of artifacts from one Nexus to other (download and later upload). I just can download the artifacts one by one, ¿Is there any way to download the entire folder? ¿Is there any other kind of operation like export/import?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have access to the nexus repository (sonatype-work\nexus\storage) in the user folder. I have got from there all the artifacts. I didn't find any way to do it from the web client.

Answer (score 4):

Nexus stores the artifacts on disk in standard Maven 2/3 repository layout, so you can just directly copy the artifacts from one storage directory to the other using whatever means you like.

After you're finished, schedule a repair index task against the destination repository so that searching for artifacts from the web UI will work. Note that your builds will work immediately after you copy the artifacts, indexes are not used by maven builds.